# .php file is getting replaced with .php.suspected - Wordpress AWS

Tags: php, wordpress, server-side-attacks

Recently my wordpress site got hacked and i solved it by reinstalling the backup version of wp-content folder and also running and repairing wordfence plugin in the site. But my website is showing an error with 500 and when i found the problem was with aws-autoloader.php file. This aws-autoloader.php is replaced with aws-autoloader.php suspected file because of which the site is not loading:

/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/amazon-web-services/vendor/aws/aws-autoloader.php

The file is getting renamed to aws-autoloader.php.suspected.

Any suggestions or opinions to fix this issue?

Comment: How about rename the file from "/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/amazon-web-services/vendor/aws/aws-autoloader.php.suspected" to "/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/amazon-web-services/vendor/aws/aws-autoloader.php" ?

Comment: Have you opened the file to check the contents ? Compare the contents of both the files and see what you get.

Comment: @floverdevel: Hi that is the solution which i am doing but it keeps changing the filename after some hours or days. I need a permanent fix for this. do you know any idea?

Comment: @kintuparantu: I didn't checked that but i deleted the renamed file and uploaded a copy from a new fresh plugin. But somehow that also keep changing.

Comment: @Zammuuz how about comparing the file which you are uploading ? Maybe that is already infected ?

Comment: @kintuparantu: I downloaded the plugin again from wordpress and extracted and uploaded to my website. Again the same file got renamed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the result of someone running a [vigilante malware cleaner](https://github.com/bediger4000/php-malware-analysis/blob/master/198.71.239.41-2018-05-19a) on your web site.

I'd look for a web shell somewhere in your WordPress installation. I wish there was a simple way to look for web shells, but there's not. If you have access to Apache's `access_log` files, see what URLs are invoked about the time of the file name change. Look at those files with a text editor to see if some stray PHP exists. The malware malware cleaner I got would also mark most web shell installations as ".suspected", so they may be installed in unique ways.